# Очистка оперативной памяти в JAVA

Tags: ram, java

На JAVA реализован сокет-сервер, база данных - PostgreSQL.
Проблема в том, что при отправке JSON сообщения размером в 1 500 000 символов память вырастает в среднем на 20 Мб, при получении JSON назад - уже 60 Мб. Используется JSON-парсер, примерная реализация обработки входящих сообщений:

```
 public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        Integer b = 0;
        a = new ServerSocket(8572);

        new conf("server.json");

        ms = new mysql();
        ps = new postgresql();

        System.out.println("[ur.java] Server started!");
        while(true) new ur(b++, a.accept());
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public ur(Integer a, Socket b) throws IOException
{
    this.cb = a;
    this.ca = b;
    q.offer(this);
    ty = new type(this);
    setDaemon(true);
    setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);
    start();
    System.out.println("[ur.java] Machine "+a+" in socket stream!");
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ca.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
}
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) ty.data(s.trim());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Исходящие сообщения из базы:

```
 ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("bla bla");
if(rs.next())
{
    socket.getOutputStream().write((rs.getString(1)+"\0").getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
```

Поскольку проект состоит из кучи классов толком выложить всё важное невозможно, если у какого-то доброго человека есть желание помочь было бы идеально связаться по Skype

Comment: - память течет постоянно и в конце-концов занимает всю доступную? Или через какое то время фиксируется на каком-то значении и не меняется сильно?
- пробовали прогнать через что то типа [mat](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)?

Comment: Доходит до максимальной и чуток спадает, сейчас сервер тестовый с 256 Мб оперативки, а мы думаем переносить в сервер для релизов, там кроме этого проекта будут другие и будет страшно если он выгрузит в конце концов 24 Гб оперативной памяти.

Висит на максималке стабильно, но порой соединение с сервером установить невозможно.

Не пробывали

Comment: br.flush()?

Comment: 256 мб для серьезного продукта на java может быть очень мало. Так что оно все доступную память и выедает. Ему же как то работать нужно?

Так как памяти не хватает, то пока ПС не подчистит, сервер не может принять новое подключение - логично.

Рекомендую прогнать на сервере с 4-8 гигами памяти и посмотреть.

Что бы процесс не выел всю память - можно ограничить. Для этого нужно запускать java с специальными ключиками - ` -Xmx` и `-Xms`. первое куча, второе стек, например  `java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M your_server`

Comment: По-моему, тебе нужно использовать "тяжёлые" переменные только один раз. Может, выполнишь профилирование и дополнишь вопрос? Я ведь сам сталкивался с такой проблемой, когда использовал FloatBuffer через BufferUtil.allocate(). В итоге я устранил утечку памяти, выделяя буффер в одну и ту же переменную.